# PHP - replace php formula

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I am trying to work out the optimal way to replace all PHP variables within a string of code with a call to an array instead as shown below.

E.g. source code string

```
$random_var_name + $random_var_name2 * $diff_var_name3
```

Transformed into

```
$varArray["random_var_name"] + $varArray["random_var_name2"] * $varArray["diff_var_name3"]
```

I had thought that `preg_replace()` was the optimal solution, but the difficulty comes with the need to perform the replacement with a sub-part of the search pattern.

Perhaps it is better to just retrieve all the variables with a `preg_match`, edit/wrap them, then perform a single `str_replace()` for each variable?

However this is probably considerably slower.

Comment: do you want to perform the calculation or only have the operation printed as it is ?

Comment: This was leading up to the formula being evaluated with `$result = eval($forumula)`. I figure this is faster than declaring the variables from the array.

Comment: Why the need for `eval()` at all?

Comment: because the formula is currently in a variable and I need the result now that I have the variables. If you can somehow manipulate the formula and get the result without a call to eval that's great.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're ultimately trying to accomplish, but the following search/replace should do what you're asking:  search: `\$var(\d)`, replace: `$varArray['var$1']`

Comment: ah I need to improve the example to show that the variable named dont all start with var.

Comment: Sounds like what you actually want to do, might rather be getting yourself an IDE with code refactoring capabilities instead …

Comment: nope, I'm already using netbeans. I am loading all the formulas from a database and evaluating them later when I have the appropriate variables. I'm trying to make some dirty design less dirty by at least having contained scope in arrays rather than having $$ in the codebase.

Comment: Here is another search/replace pattern that matches your updated question:  search: `\$([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)`, replace: `$varArray['$1']`

Comment: no don't do that, the regex I posted in my last comment should not have captured a $, make sure you have the $ outside of the parentheses.

Comment: @Jon Thanks, that worked. If you put up an answer with the preg_match Ill tick it, otherwise I can do this for you, but if I do that you dont get the rep points :(

Comment: @Programster: answer posted, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should do what you're asking:

`preg_replace('/\$([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/', '$varArray["$1"]', $input_string);`

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid to change `$var['foo']` to `$varArray["var"]['foo']` you have to check there're no `[` character after the variable name. For this use a [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\$(\w+)(?![\w\[])/', '$varArray["$1"]', $string);
```

Comment: for some reason this produced the exact same result as the previous answer for me with the following settings: `$subject = '$random1[\'hello\'] + $var2 * $var3';` `$search = '/\$(\w+)(?!`\[`)/';` `$replace = '$varArray["$1"]';`

Comment: @Programster: Sorry, I've made a mistake. See my edit.

Comment: yep that worked, produces `$random1['hello'] + $varArray["var2"] * $varArray["var3"]` Thanks for the tip